# No module named PyQt4

Tags: error

I'm totally new to python and am getting the above message when I run my script. Can't find any basic step-by-step instructions on how to import this module. Just wondering if anyone could give me some hints?

Comment: In which IDLE have you ran this script? If you use IDLE from QGIS or ArcGiS, you can't use this module.

Comment: Did you try Googling the error message? There are plenty of hits for "No module named PyQt4"

Comment: A useful-looking thread on this question exists on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994232/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt4) page should help to get you started.  You can download the module from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download).  Detailed installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/01/how-to-install-pyqt-41-python-25-and-qt_8340/).